# How to add a timestamp to a file name and move it

Tags: python

I have created the following python script that checks for the content of a source folder, copies all .txt files to destination folder, and moves all .csv files to destination folder.

This is the script-

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import time

source = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\source"
destination = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\destination"
date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
files = os.listdir(source)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source, file), destination)
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, file), destination)
```

However, I would like it to add a timestamp to the file's name before copying or moving it to the destination folder.
I have already defined `date` variable using time package but couldn't get it right.
How can that be done?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't get it right" ?

Comment: Couldn't manage to insert the timestamp before the file extension and have received "cant locate the file" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use os.path.splitext in order to separate your filename in ('basename', 'extension'), and then insert your timestamp in the middle of it. Something like

```
import os

for file in files:
  basename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)

  
  destination_name = f"{basename}{date}{extension}"
  full_destination = os.path.join(destination, destination_name)
  if extension == '.txt':
  # etc etc
```